# Clear sap like substance on underside of Chinese evergreen leaves

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, chinese-evergreen

I just recently discovered some clear sticky dots under the leaves of my Chinese Evergreen. The look and feel like some sort of sap. They can be wiped off but are thick and sticky. There isn't any visible insects that I can see. In the image I am providing they appear white but its just the reflection from the flash on my phone, they are clear. Leaves have been turning yellow on this plant for the past few months, however, I only just noticed these so I'm unsure if that is unrelated to this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You see this quite often on [aglaonema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aglaonema) and aroids.  I have seen it more often on plants in good light and think it is [guttation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttation) which is

> the exudation of drops of xylem sap on the tips or edges of leaves

Your diagnostic keys would be to rule out other sources of sticky sap such as [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_insect).  Check the underside of the leaves and the base of the stems for small hard brown bumps.  If you can flick them off with a fingernail then it could be scale.

Most likely this is just dried sap as scale is not normally found on aglo's.  No problem, nothing to do.